# Android: edittext - typing two spaces after a letter replaces the first space with a period

Tags: java, android, user-interface, android-edittext

I've noticed that in an edittext if you type one (or several) letter/s and then do a double space it replaces the first space with a period - it obviously thinks that you're trying to enter a new sentence. I want to disable this behavior - how is this possible?

```
<EditText
            android:id="@+id/someId"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:hint="@string/somehint"
            android:textColorHint="@color/somecolor"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:cursorVisible="true"
            android:textCursorDrawable="@null"
            />
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a setting of the keyboard, not your app. You can find it under

Settings > Language & input > Keyboard & input methods > (your keyboard)

As far as I am aware, it cannot be disabled. Your best bet may be to look into input method styles https://developer.android.com/training/keyboard-input/style.html

[image]

Comment: Just curious, what is the point of this behavior in the first place?

Comment: I assume it is just for convenience.  In standard English I can only think of one circumstance where a double space has been used and that is at the start of a sentence.  It is an easy way to eliminate one keystroke.

Comment: OK, I see. Thanks for helping.