# android 2 spaces replaced by comma

Tags: android, android-edittext, autocorrect

I have an EditText with max allowed chars set to 2. If there are two chars in this EditText and users press two times space, then the second char will be replaced by comma '.'

I have tried to turn off auto-correct and EditText has 'textNoSuggestions' as input type

How can I turn off this functionality?

```
<EditText
    android:maxLength="2"
    android:inputType="textCapSentences|textNoSuggestions"
/>
```

Comment: where your code ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a setting of the keyboard, not your app. You can find it under

> Settings > Language & input > Keyboard & input methods > (your
>   keyboard)

As far as I am aware, it cannot be disabled. Your best bet may be to look into input method styles https://developer.android.com/training/keyboard-input/style.html

Reference: [Android: edittext - typing two spaces after a letter replaces the first space with a period](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31679940/android-edittext-typing-two-spaces-after-a-letter-replaces-the-first-space-wi)

Comment: then why Telegram doesn't have this issue when typing a message?